# How to delete the outer circle in an image and only keep the content inside it in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to segment the bacteria types inside this microscopic image (original form is in gray), applying various thresholding operations to convert the image into binary format returns noisy results that effects the erosion/dilation/morphological operations that comes later. I want to remove the outer circle (container) of the image without affecting the instances inside it.

[image]

The issue is, having this circle will affect the quality of the binary image and hence will lead to lower quality outcomes in the next steps.

Here is the current binary image, you can see the outer circle slightly visible:
[image]

Here is the code I am currently using to get the binary form of the gray image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
kernel = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                   [-1, 9, -1],
                   [-1, -1, -1]])

sharpened_image = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(sharpened_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

binary_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 190, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(sharpened_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Original Sharpened Image')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(binary_image, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Binary Image')
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the original image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra OI has been included.